# OSMDroid - overlays icon showing only on emulator but not on phone

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have tried displaying the compass icon and the yellow person icon on the osm map, it is indeed displayed on the emulator but not on the phone. (both running Android 7.0 API 24).

this is my code

```
    mLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(new GpsMyLocationProvider(getApplicationContext()),mMapView);
    mLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    mLocationOverlay.setDrawAccuracyEnabled(true);
    mMapView.getOverlays().add(mLocationOverlay);
    this.mCompassOverlay = new CompassOverlay(getApplicationContext(), new InternalCompassOrientationProvider(getApplicationContext()), mMapView);
    this.mCompassOverlay.enableCompass();
    mMapView.getOverlays().add(this.mCompassOverlay);
    mRotationGestureOverlay = new RotationGestureOverlay(ctx, mMapView);
    mRotationGestureOverlay.setEnabled(true);
    mMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    mMapView.getOverlays().add(this.mRotationGestureOverlay);
    mMapView.invalidate();
```

The yellow person icon only shows on the emulator after I resend the location data from the emulator's settings, but at least it works.
On the phone I cannot see any changes, although other overlays like scalebar and zoom controls are showing on both the phone and the emulator.

Comment: Do you have all location services enabled on your phone, i.e. GPS and cellular network?

Comment: All permissions are checked and functional. I even tested them (location fine, location coarse, writing )